# How do I instert multiple array into mysql using laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, forms, foreach

I want to insert data from my form into mysql bu I am getting errors. How do I solve this problem.

```
        @foreach($assignments as $item)
                <input type="text" name="class[]" value="{{$item->class}}" id="">
                <input type="text" name="year[]" value="{{$item->year}}" id="">
                <input type="text" name="subject_id[]" value="{{$item->subject_id}}" id="">

                <label for="" class="ml-3 mt-2 mb-1">Score</label>
                <input type="text" name="score[]" id="" style="width: 20rem;" class="form-control ml-3">
            </div>

    $class = $request->get("class");
    $year = $request->get("year");
    $subject_id = $request->get("subject_id");
    foreach ($request->get('score') as $key => $value){

        SubmitScores::create([
            'class' => $key[$class],
            'year' => $key[$year],
            'subject_id' => $key[$subject_id]
        ]);

    }

        @endforeach
```

The error am getting is:
Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Comment: What kind of errors you have ? share your errors.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelgawad check my updated post. I have posted the error.

Comment: is it possible that you confused the key and the array? shouldnt it be `$class[$key]` etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are backwards:

```
$key[$class]
$key[$year]
$key[$subject_id]
```

Those should be `$variable[$key]`. `$key` is an integer index, like 0, 1, 2, and `$class`, `$year` and `$subject_id` (`$variable`) are arrays. So:

```
foreach ($request->get('score') as $key => $value){
  SubmitScores::create([
    'class' => $class[$key],
    'year' => $year[$key],
    'subject_id' => $subject_id[$key]
  ]);
}
```